# Conjuagate Gradient on Periodic BCs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm currently writing a CG solver. It works perfectly fine for Dirichlet boundary conditions, however, I also want it to work with periodic BCs.

The problem I'm solving is a 3D Poisson equation.

I also got a working multigrid algorithm to compare the difference between CG and multigrid. When I apply CG to the periodic case, the following happens:

- The residuual of the solution is not linearly decreasing as it should. Instead, it goes down to a small value ($10^{-10}$ or so), then increases again, and goes down again (for testing purposes, there is no tolerance to stop iterations)
- The difference of the solution I get from multigrid seems to be differing from the solution of CG by a constant.

So here are is my question:

- CG is supposed to produce a linearly decreasing residual. Is it possible that due to the non-uniqueness of solutions in a periodic case, CG suddenly "decides to go to another solution", thus resulting in the increasing residuual?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that your system matrix $A$ is rank-deficient, but your right-hand side $b$ lies in the image of $A$.

Since the search directions in the CG method are always of the form $b + A\,x$, where $x$ is an arbitrary vector, the CG method does not touch the part of the solution in the null-eigenspace (if we ignore rounding-errors).

Due to the preconditioning with multigrid, the preconditioned system has different null-space. This might explain the difference of (pure?) CG and multigrid-CG.

Comment: There is no preconditioning, you misunderstood me. Multigrid and CG are completely separate from one another and both solve the same LSE

Comment: Then simply ignore the last sentence :)